# How to ad hoc (not as a service) run Visual Studio 2010 Remote Debugger (msvsmon.exe) without UI (i.e. from PsExec)?

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

Is there a way to ad hoc (not as a service) run Visual Studio 2010 Remote Debugger (msvsmon.exe) without UI (i.e. from PsExec)?

I want to be able to run msvsmon without logging in to the server via Remote Desktop.
Also running msvsmon as a service is too risky.

Answer (score 1):

msvsmon.exe can be run from the command line and setup using command line arguments. You can get a list of these using /?.

So the answer is yes. PsExec will just execute a command remotely. You would have to either install/xcopy the remote debugger to the remote machine, then use PsExec along with a suitable msvsmon.exe command line to start it.